# How to check a checkbox using keyboard in Xcode

Tags: ios, xcode

I am trying to check the Checkbox using the keyboard rather than mouse. When i use the tab to get to the check box its skipping over the check box and moves over to next Textfiled. Is there a way such that i can move to check box using tab and select it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a system preference. Look in System Preferences > Keyboard > Keyboard Shortcuts > Full Keyboard Access. This setting determines whether Tab moves between only text boxes and lists or through all controls.

If that doesn't help you should investigate the key loop hookups in your XIB in Xcode/IB.

Comment: Its working now after changing the System Preferences. Thank u